# DNS: CNAME to enable www on subdomains

Tags: dns, subdomain

I currently have a domain `example.com` and a subdomain `sub.example.com`. What I am trying to do is to make them accessible with `www`, that is,  `www.example.com` and `www.sub.example.com`. The records look like this (using Namecheap here so not editing the raw zone-file)

```
Type   Host          Value
A      @             <ip-addr>
A      sub           <ip-addr>
CNAME  www           example.com.
CNAME  www           sub.example.com.
```

While `example.com`, `sub.example.com` and `www.example.com` is accessible, `www.sub.example.com` isn't, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need:

```
CNAME  www.sub           example.com.
```

Explanation:

(since the domain is `example.com`, it will be appended to any `Host` not ending with `.`)

`A      @             <ip-addr>` means `example.com`=`<ip-addr>`

`A      sub           <ip-addr>` means `sub.example.com`=`<ip-addr>`

`CNAME  www           example.com.` means `www.example.com`=`example.com`
(resulting in `www.example.com`=`<ip-addr>`)

`CNAME  www           sub.example.com.` means `www.example.com`=`sub.example.com`
(resulting again in `www.example.com`=`<ip-addr>`, so this last one is obviously rendundant and can be removed)

So, you have no www.sub.example.com defined anywhere, and any one of these would work:

```
CNAME  www.sub           example.com.
CNAME  www.sub           sub.example.com.
CNAME  www.sub           www.example.com.
A      www.sub           <ip-addr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this documentation https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9776/2237/how-do-i-create-a-subdomain-for-my-domain

I believe instead of 'sub' it should be 'sub.domain' for the CNAME records.

Comment: Updated question to clarify, I think the A records are correct but not the CNAME since only `www.sub.domain.com` cannot be accessed

Comment: Typed in the wrong thing. I meant CNAME. The documentation goes over this specific obstacle

Comment: You may need to modify a redirect in the .htaccess file if you cannot do so in the namecheap menu. Are your redirected to the www versions of your site when you type in the adress?

Comment: What exactly was the issue, just so I can learn from it as well?

Comment: @dusan-bajic answer gave access to `www.sub.domain.com`, seems to me like the value needs to be the domain and not the subdomain which should instead included in the host

Comment: Understood, thanks!

Comment: Explanation added.